# canopy_cli update broken -> 403 forbidden

Tags: enthought

I'm on Linux Ubuntu and the command-line upgrade doesn't work. Is there anything specific I can try to make it work or does anyone else also experience this?

```
❯ canopy_cli update
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/package_manager/package_manager_service.py", line 673, in _locked
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/package_manager/package_manager_service.py", line 389, in update_addon_index
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 145, in reconnect
    self._connect(force=True)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 149, in _connect
    self.remote.connect(self.userpass)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/joined.py", line 11, in connect
    repo.connect(auth)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 28, in connect
    self._index = self.get_index()
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 124, in get_index
    fp = self.get_data(url)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 146, in get_data
    return self.opener.open(request)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 629, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/package_manager/package_manager_service.py", line 673, in _locked
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/package_manager/package_manager_service.py", line 389, in update_addon_index
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 145, in reconnect
    self._connect(force=True)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 149, in _connect
    self.remote.connect(self.userpass)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/joined.py", line 11, in connect
    repo.connect(auth)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 28, in connect
    self._index = self.get_index()
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 124, in get_index
    fp = self.get_data(url)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 146, in get_data
    return self.opener.open(request)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 629, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Searching for updates...
Searching for updates...
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/package_manager/package_manager_service.py", line 673, in _locked
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/package_manager/package_manager_service.py", line 389, in update_addon_index
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 145, in reconnect
    self._connect(force=True)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 149, in _connect
    self.remote.connect(self.userpass)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/joined.py", line 11, in connect
    repo.connect(auth)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 28, in connect
    self._index = self.get_index()
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 124, in get_index
    fp = self.get_data(url)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 146, in get_data
    return self.opener.open(request)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 629, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/package_manager/package_manager_service.py", line 673, in _locked
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/package_manager/package_manager_service.py", line 389, in update_addon_index
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 145, in reconnect
    self._connect(force=True)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py", line 149, in _connect
    self.remote.connect(self.userpass)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/joined.py", line 11, in connect
    repo.connect(auth)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 28, in connect
    self._index = self.get_index()
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 124, in get_index
    fp = self.get_data(url)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/store/indexed.py", line 146, in get_data
    return self.opener.open(request)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 629, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/opt/canopy/base/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
No updates available.
```

Answer (score 1):

That error basically means that the file containing info on available updates isn't present on the server. (Because there are no available updates yet.)  The logging of that traceback was a bug which has been fixed for the next release.